# symmetric AES encryption with php produces different result than openssl cmd

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, php-openssl

I need to make a simple very basic encryption with **AES 128 ECB mode**.

The idea is to generate a cryptogram, code it in base64 and then decipher that text from a web service in php to process its content. Later we will increase the robustness of the encryption with a 256 key and CBC mode.

The problem is that the encrypted text generated from the openssl tool (installed by default in MacOX) generates a completely different result than the one generated by the **openssl_encrypt** function in php 7.

```
echo -n 'Sergio Sánchez' | openssl12n enc -aes-128-ecb  -a
```

Result

```
U2FsdGVkX1+wrLjaCTSM9T3WMV1YcD9Cwzj0mKBoa7M=
```

No Salt

```
echo -n 'Sergio Sánchez' | openssl12n enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -a
```

Result

```
stpJKCaUQ/Q1GLzDvqaYRg==
```

PHP 7

```
echo base64_encode(openssl_encrypt('Sergio Sánchez', 'AES-128-ECB', 'password', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
```

Result

```
dum7MBJOzIi9jvMTvEYnug==
```

How can I generate a compatible cryptogram between both tools?

Comment: ECB is not secure.

Comment: @SLaks How can I add that padding with openssl_encrypt in php?

Comment: @SLaks ok, thanks . but when using the openssl_decrypt php function with the base64 generated by the other tool, it returns an empty string.

Comment: @SLaks I'm using a 16-character password on both tools (oxPt4SyZuXCk2CSI). I've also tried specifying the key in hex with the -K option and generating another result.

Comment: What is `openssl12n` ... none of the OSX versions I have know what that is. However when I do the command with just `openssl` ... and copy/paste to a php script with openssl_decrypt(same args) ... I can confirm that the php version does not decrypt what the osx version is spitting out. I tried even with decoding the base64 before or not, and changing the options. Odd issue here.

Comment: Which version of OSX?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment that it is not the default version. It is an alias that of another installed version. alias openssl12n='/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2n/bin/openssl'

Comment: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: While I agree one should just get it working with aes-256-cbc now... it is still a very odd issue that the 128-ecb is disjointed like this between platforms.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much, then an AES 256 bit CBC mode in addition to being more secure would you avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm testing it out right now... (requires more coding since the IV is required)

Comment: CBC mode and 256-bit key will not help, the problem is elsewhere. 1. AES is block based to the input data must be a multiple of the block size: 16-bytes. If the data is shorter it must be padded to length. This can be specified in a padding option such as PKCS#7 or née PKCS#5, there is no standard default, each implementation can choose how to handle short data.

Comment: 2. The key must be one of three lengths, 128, 192 or 256-bits. If the key is not a correct length the implementation will produce an error or in some other manor handle the error such as appending nulls or deriving a key from the input. The easy solution: provide a correct length key.

Comment: Right, I'm meeting walls with multiple kinds of enc types between osx and php. Really not coming up with any answers either. So I am going to have to bow out to better encryption experts. (this question may get some notice on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: perfect thank you very much, I will raise the question at crypto.stackexchange.com. I've done it here because I wanted to make sure it was not a trivial problem.

Comment: It is a trivial problem, you need to read the documentation for OpenSSL command line and PHP. Why are you using OpenSSL command line?

Comment: @zaph The cryptogram is generated with the openssl tool and must be decrypted from php. I have tried specifying the key in hexadecimal, and the result is still different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of Command Line OpenSSL and web based encryption with the same encrypted example:

Changing the test data and key in order to reduce length issues:
key:  `'testkey1testkey1` hex: `746573746b657931746573746b657931`
data: `'54657374446174615465737444617461'` hex: `746573746b657931746573746b657931`

Test OpenSSL encryption:
echo -n 'TestDataTestData' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -a -K 746573746b657931746573746b657931
Output: `'AdLbg3zhQ2/hei0QxAdvnVZaYCTUjgmjheMmWi8Js5A='`
hex: `01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D565A6024D48E09A385E3265A2F09B390`
The first 16 bytes are the encrypted data, the last 16 bytes are padding, see note.

Test web based encryption (yes it is ECB mode):
http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=746573746b657931746573746b657931&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=54657374446174615465737444617461&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=
output: `01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D`

Comparing the two outputs (dropping the padding):
AESCalc : `01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D`
OpenSSL: `01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D`

From here you can make changes as necessary one by one.

Helpful links:
[OpenSSL enc man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/enc.html)
[AES Calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc)
[Base64 to hex decoder](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en)
[Text to Hex Converter](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php)
[PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7)

Note 1: PKCS#7 padding always adds padding so when used with data that is a multiple of the block size a full block of padding is (must be) added. If padding were not added, even in this case, it would not be possible in all cases to determine that no padding were added.

Note 2: AESCalc with padding explicitly added:
http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=746573746B657931746573746B657931&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=5465737444617461546573744461746110101010101010101010101010101010&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D
Output: `01D2DB837CE1436FE17A2D10C4076F9D565A6024D48E09A385E3265A2F09B390`